# In Vuejs, how can I display multiple columns and values from JSON

Tags: json, vue.js, mapping

I have declared the required headers to display in UI

```
 headers:{
     text: Name, value:'name'
     text: Age, value:'age'
     }
```

Here value name will be equal to key name from below json

I get json data from backend that looks like

data = item:{
         id:'1234'
         name: 'John'
         age:'22' }

Firstly I am using a data-table in which i will iterate over headers and display 
     {{header.text}}. -- Column name of table. 
But in order to display the values from data-JSON the {{header.value}} must be equal to key name in JSON. ex: name from header array is equal to item:{name:'John'}

My code:

```
       <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="data"  no-data-text="There are no data available">
        <template v-slot:headers="props">
          <tr>
            <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text">

              {{ header.text }}
            </th>
          </tr>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:items="props">
          <tr v-for="(header,index) in headers" :key="index">
            <td v-for ="(text , value) in header" :key="value">
              {{props.item.value}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
         </v-data-table>
```

I am not right on iterating over values. Please help on fetching the values dynamically.

Comment: Is the order of `headers` always the same? is `data` object an array of objects or object? ` item:{ id:'1234' name: 'John' age:'22' }` is not a correct notation.

Comment: Order of Header may or may not be same always.                                                    
            The format of data- JSON is                                                                             
         {
     "item": {
  "id": "122",
  "name": "John",
  }
              "index": 0
              }

Comment: So there's only one item in your JSON? And one row in the table? You're trying to use v-for on rows, but you provide data with just one entry.

Comment: There are around 20 items in JSON. So from that i need to pick around 15 for display and this can extend also. So i cannot manually add props.item.name, props.item.age etc because i have many items